# Ruby on Rails database table manipulation

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I am trying to manipulate the DB tables to achieve the following:

I have a table named "orders" which has_many "line_items". I want to be able to sum all the line_items into one row and group them by their name. I tried doing a nested loop but it seems very inefficient.

[image]

is there away to do something like(dummy code)

```
Orders.joins(:line_items).select("id", "sum of all line_items based on a meal name")
```

so that it populates:

```
   id   |meal 1|meal 2| meal 3|
-------------------------------
    1   |100   | 100  | 100   |
-------------------------------
    2   |300   | 200  | 50   |
-------------------------------
.
.
.
```

I'd love to get some insight! thank you

Comment: are you looking for the count of line_items/order? or the sum of the quantity of each line_items?

Comment: @Pierre-LouisLacorte sum of the quantity of each line_items so I can just loop through the order table, does that make sense?